# How to get the system task summary given by top without using top?

Tags: ps, proc, top, processes

top displays these numbers in its summary:

Tasks: 193 total,   1 running, 192 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie

I'm looking for a way to get them some other way -- running a program, parsing a /proc file.

Do you know of a way to get those numbers?

The closest I've been able to get is:

```
pgrep "" -c
192
```

and top & pgrep:

```
top -b -n 1 | head -n 2 | tail -n 1; pgrep "" -c
```

never agree ...

e.g. 194 vs 191

```
grep 'procs' /proc/stat
procs_running 2
procs_blocked 0
```

And a mention of running, sleeping, stopped, zombie here:
http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/top.c?revision=1.134&view=markup#l1025

This grep turned up a match, sleeping is 192:

```
 grep -R sleeping /proc/*/status | wc -l
```

but its way of doing sleeping and pgrep's way of doing total don't add up:

```
top -b -n 1 | head -n 2 | tail -n 1; pgrep "" -c; grep "procs" /proc/stat; grep -R sleeping /proc/*/status | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ps -eo stat | awk '/^S/ { stat+=1 } /^R/ { run +=1 } /^Z/ { zomb+=1 } { tot+=1 } END { print "sleeping = "stat" Running = "run" Zombie = "zomb" total = "tot }'
```

This will give you the same information about process state information.

R will be running processes, S will be sleeping processes and Z zombie.

Bear in mind top will always show one running process more as it will take the actual running of top into account.

Comment: For this top:
Tasks: 191 total,   1 running, 190 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
||||
That returned:
sleeping = 191 Running = 1 Zombie =  total = 192 |||| Not bad :)

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of exceptions, ps returns the correct answers.

```
local output=$(ps axo stat=)

cpu_tasks_running=$(echo -e "${output}" | grep -c  '^R')

cpu_tasks_sleeping=$(grep sleeping /proc/*/status | wc -l)
  # searching /proc gets better results than searching ps output:
  # cpu_tasks_sleeping=$(echo -e "${output}" | grep -cE '^D|^S')

cpu_tasks_stopped=$(echo -e "${output}" | grep -ci '^T')
cpu_tasks_zombie=$(echo -e "${output}" | grep -c  '^Z')

cpu_tasks_total=$(($cpu_tasks_running + $cpu_tasks_sleeping))
  # counting ps total lines never matched ps running + ps sleeping, nor top
  # replaced with math: ps running + ps sleeping
  # cpu_tasks_total=$(echo -e "${output}" | wc -l)
```